# Visual Basic write file errors

Tags: vb.net, readfile, writefile

I am working on a vb project that should be relatively straight forward.. read lines from a text file and output them to a new text file. But when I run this code in Visual Studio I keep getting the errors 'end of statement expected' (BC30205) and 'pv_objText is not declared' (BC30451). It's really very unclear to me where the error lies. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
'Variables

    Const sFilePath As String = "Contacts.txt"
    Const c_sOutputFilePath As String = "ContactsReport.txt"
    Dim fileInput As StreamReader
    Dim fileOutput As StreamWriter
    Dim sText As String = ""
    Dim sDivider As String = "--------------------------------------------------------------------"


    'Begin Code

    SetTitle("Contacts2")

    fileInput = File.OpenText(sFilePath)
    fileOutput = File.CreateText(c_sOutputFilePath)

    While fileInput.Peek <> -1

        sText = fileInput.ReadLine
        fileOutput.WriteLine("Name: " & sText)
        fileOutput.WriteLine()

        sText = fileInput.ReadLine
        fileOutput.WriteLine("Address: ")
        sText = fileInput.ReadLine
        fileOutput.WriteLine(sText)
        sText = fileInput.ReadLine
        fileOutput.WriteLine(sText & ", ")
        sText = fileInput.ReadLine
        fileOutput.WriteLine(sText & " ")
        sText = fileInput.ReadLine
        fileOutput.WriteLine(sText)
        fileOutput.WriteLine()
        fileOutput.WriteLine()

        sText = fileInput.ReadLine
        fileOutput.WriteLine("Phone: " & sText)
        fileOutput.WriteLine()

        sText = fileInput.ReadLine
        fileOutput.WriteLine("Email: " & sText)
        fileOutput.WriteLine(sDivider)
        fileOutput.WriteLine()
        fileOutput.WriteLine()

    End While

    fileInput.Close()
    fileOutput.Close()

End Sub

End Module
```

line 57 in modUtilities is where the error is occuring in the first line is here:

(it's also referring to line 59 where the pv_objText is)

```
Public Sub fileOutput.WriteLine(Optional ByVal pv_objText As Object = "")

    Dim sText As String = CStr(pv_objText)

    fileOutputwrite(sText & vbNewLine)

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error? I think it is unusual to do multiple ReadLine for a single Peek unless you're absolutely certain you know the number of lines in the input file.

Comment: hmm, well it's coming on line 57 of a separate vb file. the main vb file i'm working in is modStudent and the other is modUtilities.

Comment: i edited the post to include the area it's pointing to.

Comment: You must be passing in an empty object at some point. Possibly test String.IsNullOrEmpty against each sText before writing or include it as a test before you CStr(pv_objText)

Comment: @AndrewMortimer we do know the number of lines in the 'contacts.txt' file. the objective is to modify it and then store it to another text file.

Comment: The 2nd block of code you posted looks invalid. Don't think that'll compile.

Comment: This line is wrong:   `Public Sub fileOutput.WriteLine(Optional ByVal pv_objText As Object = "")`.  You cannot have a period in a method name.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway this is what fixed it.. very simple, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight rewrite of your method.
Adjust accordingly for your lines and see if it resolves your issue.

```
   Private Sub ReadWriteContacts()

        Const sFilePath As String = "c:\test\Contacts.txt"
        Const c_sOutputFilePath As String = "c:\test\ContactsReport.txt"
        Const divider As String = "--------------------------------------------------------------------"

        Dim linePosition As Integer

        'include tests for exists output and delete it
        'include test for missing input and report it

        Using fileInput As StreamReader = New StreamReader(sFilePath)
            Using fileOutput As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(c_sOutputFilePath)

                Do Until fileInput.EndOfStream

                    Dim sText As String = fileInput.ReadLine
                    linePosition += 1
                    Select Case linePosition
                        Case 1
                            fileOutput.WriteLine("Name: " & sText)
                            fileOutput.WriteLine()

                        Case 2
                            fileOutput.WriteLine("Address: ")

                        Case 3
                            fileOutput.WriteLine(sText)

                        Case 4
                            fileOutput.WriteLine(sText & ", ")

                        Case 5
                            fileOutput.WriteLine(sText & " ")

                        Case 6
                            fileOutput.WriteLine(sText)
                            fileOutput.WriteLine()
                            fileOutput.WriteLine()

                        Case 7
                            fileOutput.WriteLine("Phone: " & sText)
                            fileOutput.WriteLine()

                        Case 8
                            fileOutput.WriteLine("Email: " & sText)
                            fileOutput.WriteLine(divider)
                            fileOutput.WriteLine()
                            fileOutput.WriteLine()
                    End Select

                Loop
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub
```